# "Error: Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'."

Tags: vb.net

Im getting an error as in both **SAVE** and **UPDATE** button in **.CommandText**

```
"Error: Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'."
```

I don't know what is the error in both SAVE and UPDATE buttons.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    Try
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "insert into [edit$]values('" & TxtId.Text & "','" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "','" & TxtGivenname.Text & "','" & TxtGender.Text & "','" & TxtDob.Text & "','" & TxtExamdate.Text & "','" & TxtExamtime.Text & "','" & TxtStreet.Text & "','" & TxtHouse.Text & "','" & TxtPlz.Text & "','" & TxtCity & "' )"
            .ExecuteNonQueryAsync()
        End With
        FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$]")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Text)
        Return
    End Try
    MsgBox("succefully Saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnupdate.Click
    Try
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Update [edit$] set [Family Name] = '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "' where id ='" & TxtId.Text & "' and Given Name = '" & TxtGivenname.Text & "'and Gender = '" & TxtGender.Text & "'and DOB = '" & TxtDob.Text & "'and Exam Date'" & TxtExamdate.Text & "'and Exam Time = '" & TxtExamtime.Text & "'and Street Name = '" & TxtStreet.Text & "'and House Nr = '" & TxtHouse.Text & "'and PLZ = '" & TxtPlz.Text & "'and CITY = '" & TxtCity & "'"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$]")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
        Return
    End Try
    MsgBox("Succesfully updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is probably very easy:

You didn't call the `Text`-Property every time you used a TextBox value.

Look at the `TxtCity` variable:

```
"'and CITY = '" & TxtCity & "'"
```

should be

```
"'and CITY = '" & TxtCity.Text & "'"
```

Comment: @shaikizaz You should mark RamNow's answer as accepted answer. That's how this website works.

Comment: @ramnow I'm using `.Text` property of text field but still getting this error `{"Operator '&' is not defined for string ""POSId='POS.002', POSGroup =4776,"" and type 'TextBox'."} `

Comment: @OsamaRizwan Your error-message clearly states that you are trying to use the `&` operator for `string` and `TextBox`. I think that you only used the `.Text` property on one of the two values that you wanted to concatenate.

Comment: @RamNow It's my bad that I was missing `.Text` with one `TextBox` value while making a query string.